# Accessing list items of a previous list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists in python 3.x:

```
deliveryData=[[1,5,3],[2,7,8],[8,10,5]]
```

I want to compare/operate on individual items of the current list (e.g. `[2,7,8]`) with a previous list (e.g. `[1,5,3]`). How do I do that?

Testing this feature with sample code below:

```
deliveryData=[[1,5,3],[2,7,8],[8,10,5]]
for data in deliveryData[1:]:
    print(data)
    print(data[-1])
```

I was thinking I can access the list `[1,5,3]` with `data[-1]` while I am on the list `[2,7,8]` but that is not right.

Can anyone please offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just access `i-1` for previous lists, starting at `i=1`:

```
deliveryData=[[1,5,3],[2,7,8],[8,10,5]]

for i in range(1, len(deliveryData)):
    print("Current:", deliveryData[i])
    print("Previous:", deliveryData[i-1])
```

Which Outputs:

```
Current: [2, 7, 8]
Previous: [1, 5, 3]
Current: [8, 10, 5]
Previous: [2, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for the handy tip!

Answer (score 3):

`deliveryData[-1]` will always return the last element in `deliveryData`.

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) instead of bothering with indices:

```
for p_data, c_data in zip(deliveryData, deliveryData[1:]):
    print(p_data, c_data)
    # [1, 5, 3] [2, 7, 8]
    # [2, 7, 8] [8, 10, 5]
```

Unlike @RoadRunner's answer this *will* create an extra list in memory (to hold `deliveryData[1:]`). This may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just index it like this:

```
deliveryData=[[1,5,3],[2,7,8],[8,10,5]]
for data in deliveryData[1:]:
    print(data)
    print(deliveryData[deliveryData.index(data)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deliveryData=[[1,5,3],[2,7,8],[8,10,5]]
```

If you want to access first two lists in the deliveryData:

```
for i in deliveryData[:-1]:
    print(i)
```